# Error when generating ios publication file in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm going to publish an application in the apple store, where I already created the certificate for mac, I already have an apple account. What I am not getting and generate the .ipa file to attach to the project by visual studio 2017 on windows. I checked some tutorials and they told me to put the project as ad-hoc but it generates the following error

```
   Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The OutputPath property is not set for project 'App39.csproj'.  
Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of 
Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Ad-Hoc'  
Platform='iPhoneSimulator'.  This error may also appear if some other 
project is trying to follow a project-to-project reference to this project, this 
project has been unloaded or is not included in the solution, and the 
referencing project does not build using the same or an equivalent 
Configuration or Platform.  App39
```

Comment: So did you check what the error message mentioned? Is the `output path` of your App39 project set for the specified configuration and platform and are all required projects included in that build?

Comment: I think my settings are correct, however my simulator runs on the mac normally, so I put ad hoc need of some other configuration or option to be enabled ?